# HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed in Jmeter Ajax type Login in .net

Tags: .net, performance, authentication, jmeter, get-request

[image]Unable to perform Load test , for Ajax type Login form, It through error

> Response headers:
>   HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
>   Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE

for "Post" type form , and while using "Get" type request it gives error like

> Response headers:
>   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>   Content-Length: 298
>   Content-Type: text/html

My Platform login link open on modal type pop, in ajax form, but while performing the same action in normal platform(URL type Login) it does work properly fine, Kindly give any Suggestion,
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into `Exceeded maximum number of redirects: 5` error it looks like default maximum number of redirects is not enough for your application.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (it lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   httpsampler.max_redirects=10
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Check if the error is still there. If yes - increase the value and restart JMeter one more time.

However this usually indicates failed login. Have you correlated dynamic parameters like [VIEWSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx)? If not - check your recorded login request for dynamic parameters and handle them properly. See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for more detailed explanation and end-to-end walkthrough.